# Error Subscript out of range while adding new private sub in existing worksheet during runtime in excel

Tags: excel, vba

**OBJECTIVE:** To add new private sub in existing worksheet during runtime.

**CODE:**

```
Dim SheetModule As CodeModule
Set SheetModule = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(GetWSName).CodeModule

SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Dim RowNum, ColNum As Integer"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Dim wb As Workbook"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Dim ws As Worksheet"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "RowNum = ActiveCell.Row"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "ColNum = ActiveCell.Column"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Set wb = ThisWorkbook"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Set ws = wb.Worksheets(GetWSName)"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Call OpenAnnualLinkRawData(ws.Cells(RowNum, ColNum))"
SheetModule.InsertLines SheetModule.CountOfLines + 1, "End Sub"
```

**ERROR:** Subscript out of range in line `Set SheetModule = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(GetWSName).CodeModule`

Comment: What is `GetWSName`?

Comment: hi @SSlinky thank you for your reply. GetWSName is a variable where i can use to pass the name of the sheet.

Comment: Name of the sheet should be the codename, not the name on the tab (though those two could be the same...)

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams thanks for your reply. i even use the hard code sheetname like wb.VBProject.VBComponents("My Sheet").CodeModule and still got the same error.

Comment: "my Sheet" is not a valid codename?  Perhaps `wb` points to the wrong workbook?  Would help to show more of the code leading up to what you already posted.

Comment: hi "my Sheet" is the name of my worksheet which is available in my workbook. wb is a valid workbook. even i used ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("my Sheet").CodeModule still doesnt work. i'm not quite sure why the error falls into this line

Comment: Please, try `wb.VBProject.VBComponents(wb.Worksheets("My Sheet").CodeName).CodeModule`

Comment: hi @FaneDuru. i have one problem. upon running this procedure from a loop procedure. the userform suddenly disappear.

Comment: Without seeing all involved code, I am afraid I cannot understand what's happening. Do you use any of the form events? I suppose that the form is shown as Modeless (letting Excel to do something else with the form being visible). Is this supposition correct?

Comment: Worth noting you can instead use `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` in the `ThisWorkbook` code module: if you do that there's no need to add code to any new worksheet you create in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

try, in tools/references `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility` must be checked

the `linenum=3` is just coz i have `Options Explicit` enabled so the code will be inserted below it

```
Sub AddHyperlinkMacro()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.codeModule
    Dim linenum
    
    'Set the worksheet to add the macro to
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("my sheet")
    
    'Check if the macro already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(ws.CodeName)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.codeModule
    
    With CodeMod
        'Search for the macro in the code module
        linenum = .CountOfLines
        Do Until .Lines(linenum, 1) Like "Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink*"
            linenum = linenum - 1
            If linenum = 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop
        
        'If the macro doesn't exist, add it to the code module
        If linenum = 0 Then
            linenum = 3
            .InsertLines linenum + 1, "Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)"
            .InsertLines linenum + 2, "Dim RowNum, ColNum As Integer"
            .InsertLines linenum + 3, "Dim wb As Workbook"
            .InsertLines linenum + 4, "Dim ws As Worksheet"
            .InsertLines linenum + 5, "RowNum = ActiveCell.Row"
            .InsertLines linenum + 6, "ColNum = ActiveCell.Column"
            .InsertLines linenum + 7, "Set wb = ThisWorkbook"
            .InsertLines linenum + 8, "Set ws = wb.Worksheets(ws.Name)"
            .InsertLines linenum + 9, "Call OpenAnnualLinkRawData(ws.Cells(RowNum, ColNum))"
            .InsertLines linenum + 10, "End Sub"
            MsgBox "Macro added successfully."
        Else
            MsgBox "Macro already exists."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much @FaneDuru and @Tim Williams. Since "My Sheet" is it not my original sheet name. so need to get the code name.

wb.VBProject.VBComponents(wb.Worksheets("My Sheet").CodeName).CodeModule

credit belongs to @FaneDuru and @Tim Williams.